# Application Launch Image for iPhone app does not zoom-in

Tags: ios

When I touch the Application Icon of my app in my iPod touch (2nd generation), the app launches but shows the Application Launch Image after a momentary black screen. The Application Launch Image (splash screen) does not zoom-in. For most of the apps the splash screen nicely zooms in. How do I get the same behavior in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time of experimentation, I was able to find the solution. The zoom-in effect is happening only when I explicitly mention the image name for the Launch Image attribute in the .plist file.

Answer (score 1):

check [this](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/06/22/creating-splash-screen-tutorial-for-iphone/) . Also, the images you provide need to be of the right size!